# Camunda cockpit does not show certain icons in the BPMN canvas

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Camunda cockpit (in version 7.7.0) is running within a secure environment without internet connection, i.e. neither the Camunda server nor the client can talk with the outside world.

Observation: **Both the gateway and the message icons are not shown.** On an identical Camunda-installation on a normal windows box with internet, the very same BPMN-process looks fine.

I tried analyzing the website e.g. with Chrome's developer tools, inspecting elements of the Camunda page, but I could not determine who the BPMN diagram rendered. Does Camunda rely on pictures from a thirdparty server?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Which Camunda version?

Comment: @thorben: I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: There was a bug in a certain Chrome version with rendering diagrams, see https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/issues/671. Do you use the latest Chrome version?

Comment: I am using Chrome 57.0.2987.110.

Comment: Okay, then try the latest version.

Comment: @thorben It worked, thanks a lot! With the newest version of Chrome the icons are back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: Using Chrome's version 60 solved the issue.